# Is proxy traffic monitored by loopback device?

Tags: proxy, network-interface, loopback

I understand loopback device acts like a mirror interface to my localhost.

When I do `ifconfig` on my Ubuntu machine, I get this

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5253062 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5253062 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1202256159 (1.2 GB)  TX bytes:1202256159 (1.2 GB)
```

See the `RX bytes` and `TX bytes`. From this, am I supposed to assume that my internet traffic is passed through `lo` if I am using a proxy in my browser?

Comment: Are you using a [SOCKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) proxy [set up with SSH](http://support.moonpoint.com/blog/blosxom/2006/11/28#ssh-proxy) and listening on the [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) address, 127.0.0.1, rather than an external IP address for the proxy server address? I'd expect browsers on the system using that type of proxy connection to use lo.

Comment: @moonpoint No. I simply copied a SOCKS proxy IP and port from [hidemyass](http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/) list and rerouted my browser traffic through it.